# Watson Speech to Text Streaming

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I plan to use Watson speech to text service in a chat bot. Although the testing works perfect locally (using audio files and also for streaming), once the app is deployed the service performs quite badly - mainly latency and problem with word recognition. Any ideas how can I improve that?

Comment: You need to explain more what do you mean by "badly".

Comment: what is the issue? do you see added latency?

Comment: yes the main issue is the latency